# SecurityNegotiationException in WCF Service Hosted on IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, web-config

I have hosted a WCF service on IIS. The configuration file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in
    machine.config.comments usually located in
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config
-->
<configuration>


    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>


    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>

    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this
            affects performance, set this value to true only
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="false">

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          </assemblies>

        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration
            of the security authentication mode used by
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user.
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs
            during the execution of a request. Specifically,
            it enables developers to configure html error pages
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->


      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpModules>


    </system.web>

    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>

    <system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
        <webServices>
          <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
          <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
          <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
        </webServices>
        <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
      </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="IISTest2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="IISTest2.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IISTest2.IService1">
          <!--
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IISTest2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The client configuration file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://yyy.zzz.xxx.net/IISTest2/Service1.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServTest.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I tried to access the service from client application, I got

> SecurityNegotiationException

and details are

> Secure channel cannot be opened
>   because security negotiation with the
>   remote endpoint has failed. This may
>   be due to absent or incorrectly
>   specified EndpointIdentity in the
>   EndpointAddress used to create the
>   channel. Please verify the
>   EndpointIdentity specified or implied
>   by the EndpointAddress correctly
>   identifies the remote endpoint.

If I host the service on an ASP.NET development server, it works well, but if I host on IIS, the above mentioned error occurs.

Comment: Is your IIS installed on the same machine as client?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka : Its installed on same machine. I also tried by hosting the service on another IIS, result is same. :(.

Comment: what is your user permission?is it Administrator?what user you set in the directory security tab->authentication method ?

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the clientCredentialType in your client code is set to "windows". This uses the built-in Windows authentication, so maybe the user the client is running under does not have appropriate permissions on the service host machine.

Having said that, I am not sure what it should be, but it might be a path worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the `<identity>` nodes from client and server configuration. This might already make it work. If this does not work yet, I would copy the `wsHttpBinding` from the client to the server configuration. There could still be something missing but you should be closer.

There is however another issue: I think you should be clear on what kind of security you want. You have quite a mix up of different settings (e.g. You configured security mode `Transport` but you also have settings for `Message` security. I think [this](http://marbie.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/kerberos-delegation-and-service-identity-in-wcf/) helped me to set up Kerberos for WCF. Everything is done in code, but you can easily guess what the configuration would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Check *[WCF stateful security context token and service accounts](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/matthall/archive/2009/11/05/wcf-stateful-security-context-token-and-service-accounts.aspx)* and see whether it helps.

Comment: I went thru the article, however did not get what exactly I need to do :(.

Comment: @Ram: what is your iis version?

Comment: after hosting the service in IIS did you get any error while calling the service from browser?

Comment: No, I did not get any error. I browse the service from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new test application and add a service reference to the service hosted on the IIS.
When it's done, check the security configuration in the client app.config. Then it is only a matter of spotting the differences with the original client app.

Usually, this exception is raised when the security configurations are different between client and server, WCF is not able to find a common set of security policies that satisfies both parties.

Comment: Do you mean by a new console app? The current client app is winform app I created just to test this service.

Answer (score 0):

If your IIS is a member of an Active Directory domain, it must have a valid service principal name (SPN) (see: [Setspn on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773257%28WS.10%29.aspx))

You must also change your client endpoint configuration to specify the expected SPN.

Try running `svcutil` against your **IIS hosted service** to generate a new client config file.

Ex: `svcutil.exe http://yyy.zzz.xxx.net/IISTest2/Service1.svc`

Then spot the `<identity>` section of the generated Endpoint. It should contain a `<servicePrincipalName>` node. Now try your client with this config file.

Answer (score 0):

The bindings section is defined on the client, but not on the server.

The difference between what is defined on the client and the defaults used on the server could be causing the problem.

The other thing that this could be is a partial trust problem. Security in WCF requires full trust for full functionality. Without this it only supports a subset of the functionality, see *[Partial Trust Feature Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186.aspx)*.